# How do I turn the following if statements into a more efficient nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have the following code and my goal is to populate a 10x48 array in python. The data however depends on a dataset which deserves a particular spot in the array. So I've been using if statements for each compute node to plot it but I want to know how to make it faster both in code and memory using nested for loops.

There are 48 columns and 10 rows.

- The 1st row each compute node will need to be in the range compute 1-1-0 compute 1-1-1 compute  1-1-2 compute  1-1-3 compute 1-2-0 all the way till 1-12-3
- the next row will have the same middle values but the last digits will now be using the numbers 4 5 6 and 7, so for example it will become 
  compute 1-1-4 compute 1-1-5 compute  1-1-6 compute  1-1-7 compute 1-2-4 all the way till 1-12-7

this will continue until the final row where the last numbers will rotate between 36 37 38 and 39

so compute 1-1-36 compute 1-1-37 compute  1-1-38 compute  1-1-39 compute 1-2-36 all the way till 1-12-39

The following code represents the if statements I started but need a more efficient way so I can save memory and get rid of any mistakes I might make in copying and pasting.

```
temp = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
for i in linesAtTime:
    if i[0] == "compute-1-1-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][0]=float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][1] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][2] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][3] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][4] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][5] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][6] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][7] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][8] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][9] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][10] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][11] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][12] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][13] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][14] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][15] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][16] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][17] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][18] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][19] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][20] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][21] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][22] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][23] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][24] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][25] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][26] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][27] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][28] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][29] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][30] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][31] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][32] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][33] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][34] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][35] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][36] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][37] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][38] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][39] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][40] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][41] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][42] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][43] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][44] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-0.localdomain":
        temp[0][45] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-1.localdomain":
        temp[0][46] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-2.localdomain":
        temp[0][47] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-3.localdomain":
        temp[0][48] = float(i[4])


    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][0]=float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][1] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][2] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-1-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][3] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][4] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][5] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][6] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-2-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][7] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][8] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][9] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][10] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-3-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][11] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][12] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][13] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][14] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-4-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][15] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][16] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][17] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][18] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-5-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][19] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][20] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][21] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][22] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-6-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][23] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][24] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][25] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][26] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-7-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][27] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][28] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][29] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][30] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-8-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][31] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][32] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][33] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][34] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-9-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][35] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][36] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][37] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][38] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-10-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][39] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][40] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][41] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][42] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][43] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-11-4.localdomain":
        temp[1][44] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-5.localdomain":
        temp[1][45] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-6.localdomain":
        temp[1][46] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-7.localdomain":
        temp[1][47] = float(i[4])
    elif i[0] == "compute-1-12-3.localdomain":
        temp[1][48] = float(i[4])
```

I have attached a psuedoillustration of my [plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyTUc.jpg)

Comment: Look into using a regular expression. If the string `i[0]` is always going to be in this pattern, the RegEx `computer-(\d)-(\d)-(\d)\.localdomain` will work for you. The appropriate package to look into is [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Hopefully that gives you a pointer but if you still can't figure it out I'll post a proper and better answer for you :)

Comment: Is linesAtTime in a consistent order?

Comment: Or event `string.split()` if you don't want to get into RegEx!

Comment: The problem is I can't wrap my head around the logic on how to scan through each compute node and getting it to the right spot in the array

Comment: @JonathonK no it is not

Comment: To be candid, it's _really_ hard to understand your explanation, and I skipped your whole explanation at first, honestly. Assuming that all you'll need to determine a position in the array is to know what the three numbers are, you simply need to extract those numbers from the string. You can do that with regex or string.split as @AriCooper-Davis said above.

Comment: Is there some kind of simple function you could write that will take, for example, "1, 12, 3" (the three numbers) and return "1, 48" (the position in the array) back to you?

Comment: I would recommend sorting your data first and then populating your array. You would have to write your own sort method, because a straight string compare will not give you a good order.

Comment: @Andrew well that's what I'm trying to figure out. Previously I was just to use a bunch of if statements as shown in the code but now I want to use nested for loops and possibly the modulus operator to look through the compute node. Because finding the position is as simple as incrementing column by column then switching to the next row.  I just need to find the data associated with the spot tha's supposed to go with it.

Comment: Can you clarify your logic for converting the triplets into doublets? It appears the leading doublet index is ``triplet[2] // 4``, and the other is ``triplet[1] * 4 + triplet[2] % 4``, is this correct? Is ``triplet[0]`` used for anything?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is super sloppy because I wasn't able to run or test this at all, but you can try something like this.

```
def main():

    # ...

    number_of_rows = 12
    number_of_columns = 48

    temp = [[0] * number_of_columns for _ in range(number_of_rows)]

    lookup = {}

    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        for column in range(number_of_columns):
            key = "compute-{}-{}-{}.localdomain".format(1, (column // 4) + 1, (column % 4) + (row * 4))
            value = row, column
            lookup.update(key, value)

    for i in lines_at_time:
        row, column = lookup[i[0]]
        temp[row][column] = float(i[4])

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```